# Create new page in sub directory - Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I'm learning Laravel 8 right now and i have some issue with create new page ***about us*** and that will be stored into new folder named ***about*** . But when i open ***web.php*** file and add:

```
Route::get('/about/', function () {
    return view('about');
});
```

I get a message ***InvalidArgumentException. View [about] not found.*** When i change ***Route::get('about/', function () {*** i get ***404 page***. But when i change file name from ***about.blade.php*** to ***index.blade.php*** in sub folder called ***about*** on refresh i don't have any error's but design is from home page. I try to found a solution on Google, but i didn't find any example that will help me. To be clear, i have create new folder called ***about*** in folder ***resources/views/*** and in file ***web.php*** add code i write above. Thanks for help.

Comment: this one also works if your folder and blade file name are not wrong then return view('about.about')

Answer (score 0):

If you created the `about.blade.php` file inside `resources/views/about` then you should call the view method like this: `return view('about.about')`.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the issue. I forgot to add ***about*** to return view. So code for resolving the issue is:

```
Route::get('about/', function () {
    return view('about.index');
});
```